# 'Creating pointer to member of non-class type 'T*'' compiler error

Tags: c++, c++17

In the code below, I am trying to specialize FieldCompare template

```
struct A
{
    size_t key;
};

    template <class T, class Field, Field T::*field_ptr>
    class FieldCompare
    {
    };


    template <class T, class Field, Field T::*field_ptr>
    class FieldCompare<T *, Field, field_ptr>
    {
    };

int main()
{
    FieldCompare<A *, size_t, &A::key> comp;

    return 0;
}
```

but getting 'creating pointer to member of non-class type 'T*'' compiler error.

what is wrong in this code?

**EDIT1:**

See the [life example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Vai6YVoViK9nDXOy) of what I am trying to do. It is a specialization of a comparer for using with std::set and std::set, for example

Comment: See the life example of what I am trying to do: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Vai6YVoViK9nDXOy It is a specialization of a comparer for using with std::set<A> and std::set<A *>, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you cannot identify a member of `T` through `T::*ptr` when `T` is a pointer. With the `<type_traits>` header, however, you can get around this by having the base template this way:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class Field, Field std::remove_pointer_t<T>::*field_ptr>
class FieldCompare
{ /* ... */ };
```

and the specialized version

```
template <class T, class Field, Field std::remove_pointer_t<T>::*field_ptr>
class FieldCompare<T*, Field, field_ptr>
{ /* ... */ };
```

Only having the `std::remove_pointer_t` in the partial specialization doesn't work, as this wouldn't be a specialization.